# Unit test for creating a SharePoint site fails

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have some code that creates a SharePoint site.

When the code runs as part of the solution it works. However, when I run it as a unit test I get the following error:

> The test adapter 'WebHostAdapter'
>   threw an exception while running test
>   'CreateSiteTest'. The web site could
>   not be configured correctly; getting
>   ASP.NET process information failed.
>   Requesting
>   'http://localhost/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd'
>   returned an error: The remote server
>   returned an error: (500) Internal
>   Server Error. The remote server
>   returned an error: (500) Internal
>   Server Error.

I have the following tags on my test:

```
[TestMethod()] 
[HostType("ASP.Net")] 
[UrlToTest("http://localhost/SitePages/Home.aspx")]
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint unit testing requires a minimum of Visual Studio 2010 with [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en) installed. It resolves issues with Visual Studio 2010 (a 32-bit application) operating with SharePoint 2010 (a 64-bit application).